# Reference in the deployment does not match the identity defined in the application manifest

Tags: azure, connection, biztalk, hybrid

I searched a lot on this error but didn't find any solutions that applied to AZURE.  I'm creating a hybrid connection according to these instructions:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-hybrid-connection-connect-on-premises-sql-server/

Everything is good until Section D, Step 4 "Under On-premises Hybrid Connection Manager, choose Click here to install."

When I do that, a small window pops up with an animation as if a file transfer is taking place.  Then a message that says "Cannot Start Application.  Contact the Application Vendor".

I have access to a log file that has this error detail:

> System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException
>   (SubscriptionSemanticValidation)
>         - Reference in the deployment does not match the identity defined in the application manifest. 
>         - Source: System.Deployment
>         - Stack trace:          at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest
>   deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri,
>   IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri&
>   appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)            at
>   System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest
>   deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, Uri&
>   appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)            at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState
>   subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId,
>   TempDirectory& downloadTemp)          at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState&
>   subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)          at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri
>   activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String
>   deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings,
>   String& errorPageUrl)             at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object
>   state)

Any ideas?  thanks

Comment: Running Window 7 PRO 64-bit, IE 11.  Have all .Net runtimes installed from 2.0 thru 4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known issue with the ClickOne app of Hybrid Connection Manager.

The temporary workaround provided by the PG is (Until it is resolved):

1. Uninstall HybridConnectionManager.
2. Download and install [HybridConnectionManager.msi](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9847760)
3. From Powershell (admin mode) invoke Set-HybridConnectionManagerConfiguration      -ManagementPort 9352
4. From the Azure Management Portal, copy the      Primary On-Premises Connection String and add it to the      HybridConnectionManager by invoking Powershell command

`Add-HybridConnection –ConnectionString “<copied connection string>”`

---

Check the following link for more details : [Hybrid Connection - Click Once Fails](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/7c9f8bbc-42c8-468a-acbe-2d104c00fbed/hybrid-connection-click-once-fails?forum=azurebiztalksvcs)

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the following blog, it contains step by step solution for the same problem:
http://azureguy.com/azure/click-once-error-while-creating-the-hybrid-connection-through-azure-websites-biztalkmobile-services/